How can i remove containers spaces
im wondering if you can specify a custom width or height to your container when using a bootstrap and if will not affect the default responsiveness of the bootstrap container. Now, this is my main question how can i remove the space below my content in the bootstrap container , this is the screenshot screenshotand this is the code. i've added a border so i can clearly see if the space at the bottom will be removed.
<footer class="border">

            <div class="container border ">
            
                <p class="light">2024 © Secured E-Voting System for <span class="text-primary">Sulivan National High School</span></p>
                
            </div>
    </footer>

i've tried using mb-0 and pb-0 and it still doesn't work and also i've tried using d-flex align-items-end to align the contents at the bottom of the container but it still doesn't work.

What CSS do you see beng applied when you use your browser's devtools inspect facility?

This issue might not because of bootstrap container, but because the <p> tag get by default margin bottom in bootstrap.


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <footer class="border">

        <div class="container border ">

            <p class="light mb-0">2024 © Secured E-Voting System for <span class="text-primary">Sulivan National High
                    School</span></p>

        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



